# outgoing mail server on odoo with privateemail

Tags: email, nginx, odoo

I have trouble establish a connection and creating an outgoing mail server in Odoo 16, provider privateemail from namecheap.

[image]

These are the logs I received before I received an error.

```
2023-05-04 20:14:42,159 990486 INFO mail-test werkzeug: 46.217.59.86 - - [04/May/2023 20:14:42] "GET /websocket HTTP/1.0" 400 - 1 0.000 0.003
2023-05-04 20:14:53,501 990483 INFO mail-test werkzeug: 46.217.59.86 - - [04/May/2023 20:14:53] "GET /websocket HTTP/1.0" 400 - 1 0.000 0.003
2023-05-04 20:15:09,801 990490 INFO mail-test werkzeug: 46.217.59.86 - - [04/May/2023 20:15:09] "GET /websocket HTTP/1.0" 400 - 1 0.005 0.004
2023-05-04 20:15:23,850 990484 INFO mail-test werkzeug: 46.217.59.86 - - [04/May/2023 20:15:23] "GET /websocket HTTP/1.0" 400 - 1 0.000 0.003
2023-05-04 20:15:26,102 990486 INFO mail-test werkzeug: 46.217.59.86 - - [04/May/2023 20:15:26] "GET /websocket HTTP/1.0" 400 - 1 0.000 0.003
2023-05-04 20:15:30,835 990492 INFO mail-test werkzeug: 46.217.59.86 - - [04/May/2023 20:15:30] "GET /websocket HTTP/1.0" 400 - 1 0.000 0.003
2023-05-04 20:15:32,105 990482 INFO mail-test werkzeug: 46.217.59.86 - - [04/May/2023 20:15:32] "GET /websocket HTTP/1.0" 400 - 1 0.001 0.003
2023-05-04 20:15:32,347 990501 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=1/count=1/max=678899): Closed 1 connections to 'application_name=odoo-990501 user=odoo16 sslmode=prefer dbname=staging' 
2023-05-04 20:15:32,367 990501 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=1/count=1/max=678899): Closed 1 connections to 'application_name=odoo-990501 user=odoo16 sslmode=prefer dbname=test' 
2023-05-04 20:15:32,383 990501 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=1/count=1/max=678899): Closed 1 connections to 'application_name=odoo-990501 user=odoo16 sslmode=prefer dbname=mail-test' 
2023-05-04 20:15:40,147 990502 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=1/count=1/max=678899): Closed 1 connections to 'application_name=odoo-990502 user=odoo16 sslmode=prefer dbname=staging' 
2023-05-04 20:15:40,161 990502 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=1/count=1/max=678899): Closed 1 connections to 'application_name=odoo-990502 user=odoo16 sslmode=prefer dbname=test' 
2023-05-04 20:15:40,176 990502 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=1/count=1/max=678899): Closed 1 connections to 'application_name=odoo-990502 user=odoo16 sslmode=prefer dbname=mail-test'
```

As an output I got this message:

```
No response received. Check server address and port number.
 timed out
```

I'm not sure what might be the issue, I tried connecting on my local computer and on another server, I was able to connect successfully which is strange.

My odoo.conf file content:

```
[options]
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo16
db_password = False
proxy_mode = True
xmlrpc_port = 8069
xmlrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
xxnetrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
db_maxconn = 678899
;dbfilter = automatdb_004
limit_memory_hard = 2684354560999
limit_memory_soft = 21474836489999
limit_request = 81922999
limit_time_cpu = 999000
limit_time_real = 999000
longpolling_port = 8072
logfile = /var/log/odoo16/odoo-server.log
;db_maxconn = 678899
;memory_limit = 400M
;upload_max_filesize = 400M
;post_max_size = 400M
workers=9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by contacting the support of https://my.vimexx.be/. They informed me that Odoo was hosted on a VPS and the ports 465 and 587 were closed.

Once they opened them I was able to establish connection with privateemail.